# Find the Linear Packing factor of FCC [-1 -2 1]

Tags: crystal-structure, crystallography

I have been trying to figure out this question, and essentially if I assume that the only atoms that the vector touches are the starting and ending atoms, then I get 0.58. I am trying to find a more formal method for determining linear packing factor for any vector direction in a unit cell. Can someone explain how to do this question without the need more inspection?

Comment: What is linear packing factor, to begin with?

Comment: Linear Packing =  Length occupied by atoms / Magnitude of the direction

Comment: Like this? Page 29 + 30 of https://fac.ksu.edu.sa/sites/default/files/chapter3.pdf

Comment: Yes, but it is unclear how to figure it out when it isn't an obvious direction as they have presented.

Comment: This seems to be relevant to slip planes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slip_(materials_science)). Maybe the higher order planes are not relevant for that (you are looking for high-density planes).

Comment: I think [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZ1oOvoZUC0) would help you.

Comment: I watched that, but again, the direction is obvious. Everyone knows that the vector crosses the touching edges of FCC. How do I visualize this in the [-1 -2 1] ?